# ANSI Escape sequence in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, ansi-escape

I am writing a Flask app and would like to return different output when called from `curl`.

So far, so good.
I want to use Jinja2 templates, similar to the html version to generate the response.

However, I run into problems as my ANSI escape sequences are not evaluated but printed as standard text.
I've seen many questions asked about the encoding of the variables, but it seems that nobody is trying to "evaluate" the text in the templates.

My template looks like this:

```
\033[1m This is bold \033[0m
{{ content }}
```

When I now `render_template('base.cli', content=content)` and return this to the command line, the formatting in `content` is correct, the formatting that was defined in the template is ignored.

Is there a "nice" (recommended) solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, for everybody with the same problem.

The trick is to add the codes that need to be evaluated into parenthesis.

e.g. `{{ "\033[1m" }} This is bold {{ "\033[0m" }}`